# Python os.makedirs not working in home directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python script that creates a home folder and then writes a new file #.log every time it is run.

```
import os

os.makedirs(os.path.expanduser('~/logs'), exist_ok=True)
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/logs'))
filenumber = 0
while (os.path.isfile("{0}.log".format(filenumber))):
    filenumber = filenumber + 1
log = open('{0}.log'.format(filenumber), mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
log.close
print("Log succesfully saved as {0}".format(log.name))
```

Strangely, the program proceeds normally and outputs the following(I've run it a few times)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/clockpi $ sudo python3 filetest.py
Log succesfully saved as 6.log
pi@raspberrypi ~/clockpi $ sudo python3 filetest.py
Log succesfully saved as 7.log
pi@raspberrypi ~/clockpi $ sudo python3 filetest.py
Log succesfully saved as 8.log
pi@raspberrypi ~/clockpi $
```

But theres nothing in the ~/log directory on my Raspberry Pi. Even more strangely, executing the same script by copy pasting into the Python Interpreter yields the following

```
>>> import os    
>>> 
>>> os.makedirs(os.path.expanduser('~/logs'), exist_ok=True)
>>> os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/logs'))
>>> filenumber = 0
>>> while (os.path.isfile("{0}.log".format(filenumber))):
...     filenumber = filenumber + 1
... log = open('{0}.log'.format(filenumber), mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    log = open('{0}.log'.format(filenumber), mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> log.close
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'log' is not defined
>>> print("Log succesfully saved as {0}".format(log.name))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'log' is not defined
```

But the ~/log folder is created normally. Can someone explain to me why the script does not work as expected and how I can fix it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: While using interpreter, you need to add a blank line to let interpreter know that you have done with your while loop. That is the `log = open(...`) line must occur after a new line so that you need to see the prompt as `...`

Comment: oops, in any case, the problem with os.mkdirs still exists

Comment: when running with sudo ~/log is probably not expanding to the folder you expect. Have you checked if /root/logs is created or the log files straight in /?

Comment: @Bernhard yes that is indeed the problem, how can i get the expected behaviour of creating it in home if I MUST run the program using sudo?

Comment: Use absolute path is better.

Comment: Entering `print (os.path.abspath("~/logs"))` will tell you exactly where the folder is being created.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the program without using sudo.

I am guessing when you are using `sudo` command, you are going into the context of the super user , which has a different home directory than your current user, hence you are seeing the log files getting created in `/root/logs` .